# Android Serialization

Tags: android, serialization

I have these 4 classes

```
public class Ingredient implements Serializable{

    private String mIngredientName;
    private double mQuantity;
    private String mUnits;

    // Constructors and methods here....

}
```

---

```
public class Step implements Serializable{

    private int mStepNumber;
    private String mDescription;

    // Constructors and methods here....
}
```

---

```
public class Category implements Serializable{

    private String mCategoryName;

    // Constructors and methods here....

}
```

---

```
public class Recipe implements Serializable{

    private String mTitle;
    private String mPhotoPath;
    private List<Ingredient> mIngredients;
    private List<Step> mSteps;
    private int mRating;
    private List<Category> mCategories;

    // Constructors and methods here....

   List<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<Recipe>(); // I want to save this.        Assuming that the object actually contains Recipe objects
}
```

I want to serialize the recipes object cause I don't want to use SQL database, it's overkill for me. Should the other three objects be serializable in order for this to work ?

Comment: yes, to serialize an object each of its members have to be serializable

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you want to serialize the object its other classes have to implement serializable  :). Databases are quite fun, should give then a go sometime.